# Change bootstrap layout on mobiles

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to change the layout of my template on mobiles.
My layout now is

[2][7][3]

and i want to change it to

[12]

[7][5]

on mobiles only.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"></div>
</div>
```

I understand that the changes should be done on sm and xs classes. 
Any help on that?

Comment: It not clear what you are asking. You're nesting columns for what appears to be no reason and if you're going to expand your first column from 2 to 12, wouldn't you want the last one to be 5 instead of 3 in order to use the free space that's created? Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @vanburen I need to change the first nested div to take the whole width (12) when on mobile and change the last one from 3 to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to change the column classes for the smallest breakpoint (unless you're trying to do this at a different breakpoint):

`col-sm-2 to col-xs-12` and `col-sm-3 to col-xs-5`.

See example

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
      <div class="alert alert-warning">2 to 12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7">
      <div class="alert alert-info">7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-3">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">3 to 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```